# SQL Error : "Incorrect syntax near"

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database that is connected to SQL Server 2008, I am getting an error when printing database : **Printing aborted! Error 37000 (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers) - [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server] [Incorrect syntax near 'TEMP_TAB_SHEET_U17'**.

Details script as below :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [data].[TEMP_TAB_SHEET_U17](
    [TAL] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Phase] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SHT] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [PreferedSYS] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [sysdesc] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [EquipmentNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [TaskNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [TaskId] [int] NULL,
    [OTdescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OTremark] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Estimated_Man_Hours] [float] NULL,
    [EquipmentId] [int] NULL,
    [EquipmentDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TAA_ID] [int] NULL,
    [UserGroup] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [MODULE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ModuleDesc] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTTitle1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTTitle2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTTitle3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTTitle4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTNbSections] [int] NULL,
    [NbMaxTasksPerSheet] [int] NULL,
    [S1_PH] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [S1_M] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [S1_PF] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [S2_PH] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [S2_M] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [S2_PF] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [S3_PH] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [S3_M] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [S3_PF] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SHTFooterTitle12] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [data].[TEMP_TAB_SHEET_U17] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Phase]
GO
```

Query completed running with the error :

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TEMP_TAB_SHEET_U17' in the database.
Msg 1781, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

How to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Awan

Comment: the error means there is already an object named 'TEMP_TAB_SHEET_U17' in the database.   You solve the problem by not trying to create another one.

Comment: @TabAlleman - or drop the old one first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the constrain on creation:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

    CREATE TABLE [data].[TEMP_TAB_SHEET_U17](
        [TAL] [varchar](30) NULL,
        [Phase] [smallint] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        ...
        ....

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
```

Comment: Error messages appear : 
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'TEMP_TAB_SHEET_U17' in the database.
Msg 1781, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.